# Bold and italic section headings with biolinum-type1

Tags: fonts

I am using the `memoir` class and am trying to set the section headings to be both bold and italic with `biolinum-type1` font but I only seem to be able to manage one or the other even though the tex catalogue would indicate that both should be possible with this font.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{biolinum-type1}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Section titles in sans serif

\setsecheadstyle{\sffamily\bfseries\itshape\raggedright}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test Section}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your example code works fine for me.  Have you made sure your tex installation is up to date?

Comment: Running update manager for my MiKTeX installation to see if that's the problem. Thanks for that.